# How do I remove world lighting for a certain object?

Tags: lighting, world

I want to prevent a specific object in my scene from being lit by the world background. How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is possible, but a workaround would be to render that object without the world background (transparent, etc), and then add it onto the world background and whatever other objects you have in your scene in the compositor.

Someone else may have a better answer that actually solves what you're asking for, but this is a solution that would work.

Comment: You can duplicate your Scene and disable the World lighting in one and the recombine in the compositor like @ThunderBolt832 says

Comment: Thanks for restating that :). A bit simpler than the way I put it.